# Joint probability density function with complicated exponential function

Tags: probability, density-function

There is given the following function:

$f(x,y) = ce^{-4(x+1)^2-6(x+1)y-9y^2}$

In the task I am asked to do the following things

1. Find $c$
2. Marginal distribution of $X$ and $Y$
3. Probability density function of $T = x^2 + 3x +1$

I am not really able or have any idea how to solve this task. The problem is the function that does not look nice. I have already done other similar tasks, but functions in those ones were not so complicated as here.

I have heard that there is a need to use some matrix and then the determinant of it, but I can't see what values should be take into account when creating this matrix.

Comment: Looks to be the density function of a [bivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

1. To find c, calculate the integral over all x and y of f(x,y).  Adjust c so the integral = 1.
2. Calculate the integral over x to get the density function for Y and similarly integral over y to get the density for X.
3. Statement looks funny.  Why T=x+3x+1 (=4x+1)?

Comment: Like you proposed, I always use integration to get $c$ value in task like this one, however our tutor said that it's not the way here, so I am somehow confused. I think it should be $x^2+3x+1$. Probably I got it wrong while noting

Comment: Tutor  is wrong - get him to explain what he objects to.

Comment: 3. as you revised is very difficult.  Maybe it should be T=Y+3X+1.